# Compilation error while converting .m file to .exe

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to convert M-file to standalone EXE using `deploytool` UI.

I have configured both `mex` and `mbuild` correctly.

But during compilation I'm getting following error:

```
ant:
<ant>
<mkdir dir="C:\abc\for_redistribution" />
<mkdir dir="C:\abc\for_testing" />
</ant>

mcc -C -o findSignature -W WinMain:findSignature -T link:exe -d C:\abc\for_testing -v C:\abc\my_matlab.m 
Test checkout of feature 'Compiler' failed.

mcc failed.
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: if you have a concurrent license, perhaps the server run of out licenses to checkout for that particular toolbox. If you are in an academic situation (university or something) contact the administrator, maybe they can purchase additional licenses if the problem occurs often.

Answer (score 0):

I think that error message means you have the MATLAB Compiler installed, but you do not have a license for it, see [this discussion](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/121413-error-using-mcc-test-checkout-of-feature-compiler-failed) on MATLAB Answers. Are you sure you have a valid license for MATLAB Compiler? Try running `ver` at the MATLAB command line to see what you get.